# HttpClient - body content is not returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

The response is always null, but when making the API call via curl the body content is returned.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5008/Accounts/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "ACCESSTOKENHERE");

    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync("searchKeyword=" + searchKeyword);

    try
    {
        AccountListResponse response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccountListResponse>();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the headers curl sends and the headers you send are the same? I recently answered a q on here of a similar ilk (worked in browser, not in code) and it turned out the client was not sending a user agent header at all and the server was sending nothing back

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve shortened this code.. is the response data from the server actually convertible to account list response? Or is it sending something but it’s your conversion attempt that is returning the null? What does ReadAsStringAsync give you?

Comment: @CaiusJard ReadAsStringAsync returns an empty string.

Comment: use curl to call web api, works.
In code, try to call the same web api, error 401 Unauthorized

Comment: FIXED, I was missing a "?" in the query parameter!  ("searchKeyword=" ... suppose to be ("?searchKeyword=" ... I overlooked ...didnt see the ? question mark missing until now :)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you only troubleshoot help since, your problem doesnt contain sample response from your api call.

for troubleshoot,
 Read response as string. Then check you are getting a response. As well as statusCode.

```
.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

If this gives results. Then your `AccountListResponse` does not has a correct mapping to response.

Use json to c# method to generate correct object.